# Python requests got the Raw HTML data but how can i get the data from element by its id?

Tags: python, html

So I am trying to program a bot that can calculate the info that stands on a website. I got the raw html data and checked if the class was in the data. But how can I get the data between:

```
<span class="rws"> 10 + 10</span>
```

I just need the `10 + 10` part.

I can't get it to work. I've tried this:

```
import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def read():
    link = "https://www.matematikfessor.dk/adaptive_test/index/topic:minus-subtraktion--112"
    f = requests.get(link)
    htmlData = f.text
    if('<span class="math" id="MathJax-Span-15" role="math" style="width: 6.362em; display: inline-block;"><span style="display: inline-block; position: relative; width: 5.736em; height: 0px; font-size: 111%;"><span style="position: absolute; clip: rect(1.358em 1005.35em 2.557em -1000.02em); top: -2.187em; left: 0.003em;"><span class="mrow" id="MathJax-Span-16"><span class="mrow" id="MathJax-Span-17"><span class="mn" id="MathJax-Span-18" style="font-family: MathJax_Main;">2,7</span><span class="mo" id="MathJax-Span-19" style="font-family: MathJax_Main; padding-left: 0.263em; padding-right: 0.263em;">-</span><span class="mn" id="MathJax-Span-20" style="font-family: MathJax_Main;">1,57</span><span class="mo" id="MathJax-Span-21" style="font-family: MathJax_Main; padding-left: 0.315em; padding-right: 0.315em;">=</span></span></span><span style="display: inline-block; width: 0px; height: 2.192em;"></span></span></span><span style="display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; vertical-align: -0.286em; border-left: 0px solid; width: 0px; height: 1.102em;"></span></span>' in htmlData):
        print("Hej")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlData)
    quest = soup.find_all("span", class_="math")
    print(type(quest))

def main():
    read()

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use python [BeautifulSoup](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bs4) library to extract data from html tags.
Here is your solution

```
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    soup = BeautifulSoup('<span class="rws"> 10 + 10</span>')
    soup.span.string
```

after this step you will get string **10+10** as output

Comment: But the thing is that I'll never know the "10 + 10" I could be every number.

Comment: if you want to extract the integer from string then you can use regex or python split method.